# How to display the values of small size block in the stack bar below to bar?

Tags: css, jqplot

Currently i'm working on displaying stacked bar chart using jqplot plugin. I have come up with following issue:

[image]

In the last bar, the value 31% and 63% is getting displayed. How to display the values for first two blocks in same bar?

Helps and ideas much appreciated.

Update 1:

Fiddle link added in comments

Comment: i think u need to manipulate the code which produces these % values to show the actual values from the y-axis. Can u plz share some code where u r trying to do this.

Comment: Sure, by soon will share the sample codes

Comment: @Gyandeep Check the fiddle in http://jsfiddle.net/pandiyancool/RPE6h/1/

Comment: Try using a highlighter or legend options

Comment: Could you please mention the exact change.

Comment: @ppollono Could you please mention the exact change.

Comment: I have got answer form this source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525713/how-to-move-the-values-displayed-on-the-bar-to-down-to-it/20529796#20529796