# How to move the values displayed on the bar to down to it?

Tags: html, css, jqplot, bar-chart

Currently working with stack bar chart in jqplot. My doubt is how to move the value displayed on the bar to down of its bar?

[image: enter image ![description]

[fiddle avail at here](http://jsfiddle.net/pandiyancool/RPE6h/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var yAxisLabels = ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4"];
var legendValues = ["series1", "series2", "series3", "series4"];
var pLabels1 = ['70%','38%','71%','28%'];
var pLabels2 = ['27%','49%','27%','44%'];
var pLabels3 = ['2%','10%','2%','17%'];
var pLabels4 = ['1%','4%','1%','12%'];
var group4 = [52,528,129,264];
var group3 = [94,1388,394,401];
var group2 = [1446,7130,5591,1004];
var group1 = [3772,5512,14957,633];
    var series = [
                        { pointLabels: { labels: pLabels4 }},
                        { pointLabels: { labels: pLabels3 }},
                        { pointLabels: { labels: pLabels2 }},
                        { pointLabels: { labels: pLabels1 } }];
var plot = $.jqplot('chart', [[[52,1],[528,2],[129,3],[264,4]], [[94,1],[1388,2],[394,3],[401,4]], [[1446,1],[7130,2],[5591,3],[1004,4]], [[3772,1],[5512,2],[14957,3],[633,4]]], {
                stackSeries: true,
                seriesDefaults: {
                    shadow: false,
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: { fillToZero: true, barDirection: 'horizontal', highlightMouseOver: true},
                    pointLabels: {
                        show: true, stackedValue: true, location: 'w', hideZeros: true
                    }
                },
                axes: {
                     xaxis: {
                        tickOptions: {
                            show: true,
                            mark: 'cross',
                            formatString: "%'d",
                            showGridline: true
                        },
                        min: null,
                        max: null,
                        showTickMarks: true
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        ticks: yAxisLabels
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    gridLineColor: '#ffffff', /**/
                    borderColor: '#509790',
                    shadowWidth: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    shadow: false
                },              
                series: series
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution: [Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/FA4Wz/1/)

just add `css` class with name of the parent element of the graph div element and the jqplot-point-label class mix.
Look at the jsfiddle as it would make more sense there

```
.chart .jqplot-point-label {
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: Okay thats fine, but how to display the value of small size block value?

Comment: How to display value for block with blue color in bar?

Comment: jqplot will not plot values if the space is not available. if u still want to get those values you have to change the source code.

Comment: Could you please let me know where i have to change?

Comment: [Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/S7nhK/1/).  please look at the code from line 273 - 285. thats where they remove the labels which doesn't have enough space or are outside the chart. i ope this helps

Comment: even if you comment line 284, you would see all the labels come up. :)